# Read XML posted via cURL into an array for potential DB insert

Tags: php, xml

I am receiving XML POSTED via curl, and can successfully write the posted XML to a file, so I know that its being posted successfully.

I really need to access the posted XML and create an array as soon as it is received, so I can set up variables and prepare the posted XML for a database Insert.

Can anyone show an example of how I would access the XML, received as:

```
$postXML = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
    <first_name>Larry</first_name>
    <last_name>Jones</last_name>
    <url>www.somewhere.com</url>
</data>
```

I need to access `<first_name>, <last_name> and <url>` and create as variables for processing and DB inserts.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)
Load the XML string with:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($postXML);
```

Then access the data you want:

```
$first_name = (string)$xml->first_name;
$last_name = (string)$xml->last_name;
$url = (string)$xml->url;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly .. I'll read up on simplexml.